# Predict total responses to emails amongst multiple groups

Tags: predictive-modeling

I've got historical data about email characteristics (like time sent, length, topic etc.), and the respondents to these emails - I've got their IP, which is further linked to gender, domicile, employment status and so on.

The example of my datasets is shown below:

```
# dataset 1

email_id  time_sent length  topic         respondent_ip
YH2       00:02     300     advertisement  80.121     
YH2       00:02     300     advertisement  71.231

# dataset 2

respondent_ip  gender domicile employment
80.121         man    US       employed
71.231         woman  China    unemployed
```

I want to predict how many people within different 'groups' are likely to respond to the emails based on the email characteristics. So for example, **if I send an email on midnight, that is 300 characters and its topic is advertisement, how many unemployed women are likely to respond?**

I'm struggling to conceptualise what sort of model I could apply here, or even what sort of structure that model should have. Primarily, because I'm interested in so many different 'groups', I'm not sure what my response variable should be.

Any pointers here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have historical data on how many people, with certain characteristics, responded to emails previously?

If yes, then you can train a model (eg ANN, CART) using topic / gender / domicile  / employment status (and optionally size of group of these people) as input features and number of responses of that group of people (or percent of the original size) as outcome.

If you are only interested in unemployed women then use only data for unemployed women.

In any case, after training, you feed the model with an email topic and gender and employment status (and optionally how many people you target) and you get a result for how many are likely to respond from this group of people.

Comment: Yes - I have thousands of records of historical emails and respondents in the same structure as in my post. So I can easily calculate, per each email, how many people of different characteristics responded to it. Would a random forest regression work for this purpose, you think? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yes Random Forest regression can be used.

Comment: Note that using percent of population that responded instead of absolute number as outcome, might be more robust

Comment: Maybe domicile variable is bad feature to use. Take a note of it and see

Comment: Could you explain your thinking, how would percent of population be more robust? And why domicile is bad feature (as its actually one that is important for what I'm trying to do)? Thank you very much, much appreciated!

Comment: Percent would be more robust, because asolute numbers have great variation, while percent is normalised, thus can be easier to correlate. But that is a hypothesis. I doubt location of living is positively correlated to whether someone will respond to an email, but that is my view